# Debug *.tpl files in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, phpstorm-2017.2

I am working with `PhpStorm` IDE. I have configured `xdebug` and I can debug php files in my IDE and it works fine.

The problem is that I want to debug `.tpl` files too. I can debug `.tpl` files in `NetBeans` IDE! But PhpStorm does not support Smarty debuging! I have searched a lot and nothing special found.

Is it possible to debug `.tpl` files in PhpStorm? And how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must tell PhpStorm that `*.tpl` files are `*.php` files.

So we go to `File->Setting->FileTypes` and remove `*.tpl` from Smarty file type and add it to Php file type. That's all.